# How would I chi-squared test these simple results from A/B experiment?

Tags: scikit-learn, ab-test

I have results from an A/B experiment where users could do one of three things: Watch, Interact, or Nothing

My data is like this:

```
   Watch  | Nothing | Interact
A: 327445 | 271602  | 744702
B: 376455 | 140737  | 818204
```

I tried to use the chisquared test bundled with scipy. I'm completely new to data science, but I believe this is the evaluation metric I would want.

```
scipy.stats.chisquare([ [327445, 271602, 744702], [376455, 140737, 818204] ])
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=array([  3412.38826538,  41532.93339946,   3456.72996585]), pvalue=array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]))
```

This does not look like a valid result...

I even tried adding an `expected frequencies` options, but without success. Maybe I'm missing something, either about evaluating this type of data or just not using scipy correctly. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Shouldn't the null hypothesis be stated? Without it the question is ill posed IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you're trying to answer is if the action taken by a user (watch, interact, nothing) is influenced by the group they are in (A or B) you can use the chi2 test of independence.

For that you can use the scipy.stats.chi2_contingency function:

```
a = [327445, 271602, 744702]
b = [376455, 140737, 818204]

chi2, pvalue, _, _ = scipy.stats.chi2_contingency([a, b])
```

In this case it returns a chi2 test statistic of 48376.48 and a p-value of 0.0, so the null hypothesis ("action is independent of group") is rejected.

You can also use the scipy.stats.chisquare function to arrive at the same results, but other than with the chi2_contingency function you'll have to calculate the "expected frequencies" yourself. The data you have recorded are your observed frequencies:

```
obs = np.array([a, b]).astype(float)
```

(Note that I converted the numbers to float, as the chisquare function will run into some weird integer overflows otherwise...!?)

The expected frequencies are calculated like that:

```
exp = np.outer(obs.sum(axis=1), obs.sum(axis=0)) / obs.sum()
```

Finally, calling

```
chi2, pvalue = scipy.stats.chisquare(obs.ravel(), exp.ravel(), ddof=sum(obs.shape)-2)
```

returns the same chi2 test statistic and p-value as before.

Comment: In the last line you forgot "degrees of freedom". It should be `chi2, pvalue = scipy.stats.chisquare(obs.ravel(), exp.ravel(), ddof=sum(obs.shape)-2)`

Comment: Thanks for the great response! Is it common for a p-value to be returned as 0.0? I assume this means a p-value so small that it exceeds the amount of significant figures that python can store?

Comment: @OneChillDude have a look at the cumulative density function of the chi2 distribution - you can calculate the p-value of the chi2 statistic using 1-scipy.stats.chi2.cdf(x, df=2). For a chi2 statistic of x=5.991 this results in a p-value of 0.05. For x=50 it's already 1.39e-11. Your chi2 statistic is 48376.. which is really far away and thus results in a p-value of 0.0 due to loss of precision.

Comment: @stmax neat, thanks for the info. Does such a low p-value have any negative connotation for chi squared results, or is it just simply acceptable?

Comment: @OneChillDude I'd say it's acceptable... in your experiment 270k people did nothing in group A, while only 140k people did nothing in group B. That's such a huge difference that one can be almost 100% certain that it didn't happen by chance.. so a p-value of 0.0 makes total sense here.

Comment: In the context of A/B testing, shouldn't the null hypothesis be that treatment `b` doesn't change the result, and thus deriving the expected observations should depend only on `a`?